# Unity Bowling ball physics

Tags: unity, unityscript, physics-engine

I am working on Bowling Ball game for android. And I want the Bowling Ball to feel like a Bowling ball in the real world. I've already tweaked the Rigidbody values and PhysicsMaterial but it's giving me that result. So, how do I make Bowling ball like real BowlingBall in Unity?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what results you're getting currently, and how they differ from the results you want? It would also help if you show us the Rigidbody and PhysicsMaterial settings you're using currently.

Comment: @DMGregory 1. Its weight is very light and if I increase the mass it becomes slow need more force to move the ball. 2. Also added a PhysicsMaterial in Ball, but colliding with pins it makes the ball and pins more bouncy.                                                                                                 ** What I want** is the Ball should be heavy don't bounce too much 2. And after collision pins don't bounce away too much.

Comment: What are your bounciness and bounce combine settings for your physics material? You should also have physics materials on the pins as well as the ball.

Comment: maybe try adjusting gravity settings too?

Comment: @Kavinci Ball PhyMaterial (Dynamic Friction = 2, Static Friction = 2, Friction Combine = Multiply, Bounce Combine = Multiply). And I don't have PhyMaterial on Pins. What's your recommendation?

Comment: @Nick I haven't tweaked gravity settings. I'll try gravity setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we first need to answer How does a bowling bowl move?

This is kind of complicated. When a person throws the ball they put some forward momentum on the ball as well as some rotational momentum. The initial contact with the lane is in  kinetic friction. The ball glides with almost no forces transferred between the ball and the lane. This is how a player puts a spin on the ball to make it travel in an ark. If the ball is thrown soft enough at some point it may "catch" the lane, start spinning and convert to static friction. At this point the ball will roll.

So what do we need? We need to set the ball to the right size and weight. We need to throw it with enough force, and rotational force. This may be way higher, and move way faster than looks normal. We need to set the lane to very low kinetic friction, and low static friction.

Also use the sphere collider :)

More research on bowling. A bowling ball is also not a single density object.

> The bowling ball consists of a hard outer shell with a weight block in
>   the core (the inside of the bowling ball). The mass and shape of the
>   weight block affects the spin of the bowling ball and how it curves as
>   it rolls down the lane. These play an important role in the physics of
>   bowling and (consequently) a bowler's performance, as will be
>   discussed.

Here is a detailed write up with images
https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-bowling.html

Comment: Note that it “catches” the lane as the oil on the lane decreases, thus increasing the coefficient of friction. Different bowling venues have different oil patterns, with different lengths, that bowlers must take into account when trying to get the optimal spin down the lane.